# Calling .net core dll from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have made a dll in .net core 6 and I want to call it in an asp.net project having framework 4.8. I just clicked Add Reference and browsed the dll. When I run the project, it gives the following exception:

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You can't. That's it. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. You can't call .NET Core libraries from .NET Framework libraries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing .Net Framework app with .Net Core library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390796/mixing-net-framework-app-with-net-core-library)

Comment: Another similar [Invoke method from .Net Core library in .Net framework application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771329/invoke-method-from-net-core-library-in-net-framework-application): You can't, it has to be a .NET Standard library

Comment: What are you trying to do? If this is a new application it should target .NET Core, not .NET Framework. If you want to use one of the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` packages, you won't have problems if you add them directly, as they target .NET Standard 2.0. If you use a library that uses the Microsoft.Extensions.*, you should change it into a .NET Standard library if you want to use it in .NET Framework applications

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have created a .net core dll to distribute. I am trying to create a web UI as a demo app for the dll. I don't have any experience in creating web UIs with .net core this is why I am using simple asp.net framework 4.8.

Comment: That's not a "simple" scenario. Besides, the only thing that's not migrated to ASP.NET Core is WebForms, an obsolete technology that shouldn't be used for new applications. All other UI stacks (MVC, Web API, Razor Pages) are available in ASP.NET Core

Comment: Check for example [Tutorial: Get started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You could try targeting it to .NET Standard 2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0. It could then be consumed by .NET Framework 4.8. Your ability to do this would depend on what libraries you consume and all of them having a .NET Standard 2.0 or lower target.